# How to terminate a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I use `#` to comment out the commands that I don't need in a Dockerfile. Does anybody know if there is a command (something like exit) to terminate a Dockfile so that all the lines below it won't be run? Thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Simply comment them out, or remove the lines.

Comment: If this is principally for debugging purposes, `docker build` prints out intermediate image IDs along the way, and you can `docker run --rm -it 0123456789ab /bin/sh` to get a debugging shell against any of them (even if the final build fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically I see coupe of options:

1. Comments # are the way to go.
2. Create two separate docker files. Like Dockerfile.dev or Dockerfile.prod and specify them via build (which I personally do not like and do not practice)

Pls describe your initial intent (why do you need it) and maybe we will figure out an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide my use case, as the original poster has not responded. The use case is for debugging purpose, and I may be making iterative changes.  Say I have a 100-line Dockerfile, and I want to run till line 20 and then quit. I could do it in bash script (by adding statement exit 0). So does Dockerfile support something like exit? This feature is definitely only nice-to-have, as I know I can simply make a copy and remove the rest, but it is just additional steps I would like to avoid. So this is try to reduce edit-copy-run to edit-run I am doing many trial-and-error iterations.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, you can halt the execution of the Dockerfile by adding a call that produces an error. I like to use `RUN exit 1` to have the shell produce a nonzero exit status:

```
# Lines you want to execute
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo "Hello world!" > /hello

# Halt execution
RUN exit 1

# Lines that will not be executed:
RUN rm -rf /
```

On my system this results in the output:

```
$ docker build .
(several lines skipped)
 => [2/4] RUN echo "Hello world!" > /hello                                 2.7s
 => ERROR [3/4] RUN exit 1                                                 0.7s
------
 > [3/4] RUN exit 1:
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |
   5 |     # Halt execution
   6 | >>> RUN exit 1
   7 |
   8 |     # Lines that will not be executed:
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c exit 1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

$
```